# Position of "nicht" in sentences

Tags: word-order, negation

I'm confused about the word order with the word "nicht".

For example, you say

> Sie geht nicht nach Hause.

but why is "nicht" at the end here?

> Sie wäscht ihre Hände nicht.

when you want to say that she doesn't wash her hands, instead of "Sie wäscht nicht ihre Hände."? 
Or similarly (I guess you could say that she washed something else, but not her hands), why can't you say

> Sie geht nach Hause nicht.

?

Comment: That's maybe not an exhaustive answer, just some examples of use. Am equally eager to see what we may get, if there is a general rule. I have no idea, even as a German. I would equally use "Sie wäscht nicht ihre Hände" und "Sie wäscht ihre Hände nicht", the latter may be to emphasize some defiance in a reaction, but that's only a gut feeling, i have nothing substancial.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf I read that other question, but it uses clear rules why they put "nicht" at the end, for example "gern" is an adverb, hence it goes at the end, "Film" is a noun, so it goes at the end. I'm confused why in the second sentence putting "nicht" at the end is outright wrong, whereas in the former both go (tho one is less common). Both sentences have verb, noun in accusative, so I struggle to find a nice rule such as "adverb, so 'nicht' goes at the end".

Comment: @a_donda _"Sie wäscht nicht ihre Hände"_ That at least sounds unusual for me.

Comment: @a_donda I'd understand that the speaker in this case wants to stress that she is washing something - but it definitely isn't her hands.

Comment: For example, or stress the fact that she is somewhat obstinate in washing her hands. Depends if emphasis is on "wäscht" or on "nicht".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, *nicht* negates item it leads.

> Sie geht **nicht nach Hause**.
>
> Sie wäscht **nicht ihre Hände**.
>
> **Nicht sie** wäscht ihre Hände.

And now the exception. Actually, it still follows the rule but needs additional reasoning. Let's use a **separable verb** for illustration:

> Sie **geht** dieses Wochenende **nicht aus**. (ausgehen – to go clubbing)

See how this works? This *nicht* leads the predicate verb. Well, at least the separable prefix which sticks to the end even in main clauses. Only the conjugated stem of *ausgehen* is moved to V2 position. And this is just the same for non-separable verbs.

> Sie **wäscht** ihre Hände **nicht**.

---

But what about

> <s>Sie geht nach Hause nicht.</s>

That one is really tricky. It follows the above rule, but no German speaker would put it that way. The following one is fine though:

> Sie geht im Haus nicht.

My guess is this is because it is an adverbial of direction. These seem to be special, they want to be negated instead of the predicate verb. It doesn't apply to other adverbials.

Comment: Otoh, to denote that something won't work inside the house the phrase "Das geht im Haus nicht." is normal use.

Comment: Yes, it's only directions that are special. Why? No idea.

Comment: I guess you could say "Sie geht nicht dieses Wochenende aus" to stress that she will be going out some other weekend, just not this one. I'd chalk the "Sie geht nach Hause nicht" up to being an exception, but saying "Eine Kurve ist gerade nicht" also sounds wrong.

Comment: But *Eine Kurve ist **es** gerade nicht.* is perfectly okay. Your example is another tricky exception.